# Show column with information in new column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table here in this example with 2 order numbers under sub-orders. Now I need the info in the user_c_56 column in the sub-orders as well.

The `aunr` column is assigned to the order number. Here is the original table and the way I would like it to be.

[image: original table]

[image: As she should be]

Here my query:

```sql
SELECT b.order_nr,
       b.user_c_56,
       b.aunr,
       s.a_atufe,
       z.mehrfach_kz,
       b.soll_dauer
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz] z
     JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b ON z.auftrag_nr = b.aunr
     JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrag_status] s ON b.auftrag_nr = s.auftrag_nr
WHERE s.eingeplant = ('M');
```

Comment: Images of data don't help us help you; we can't use images, we can't copy and paste them into our IDE and extract the text. Take the time to post your data in a *consumable* format (DDL and DML statements work best). Also your attempt uses 3 tables but you only supply data for 1 table/dataset. Show us what the data looks like in the table(s), not what it looks like after your (failed) attempt(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, an approach based on windowed function (`MAX` in the example) is a possible option:

```
SELECT 
   b.order_nr,
   b.user_c_56,
   b.aunr,
   s.a_atufe,
   z.mehrfach_kz,
   b.soll_dauer,
   MAX(CASE WHEN b.order_nr = b.aunr THEN b.user_c_56 END) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY b.aunr) AS user_c_56
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz] z
JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b ON z.auftrag_nr = b.aunr
JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrag_status] s ON b.auftrag_nr = s.auftrag_nr
WHERE s.eingeplant = ('M')
```